# Difference between local, static and global functions?

Tags: c

What are the differences between local functions, global functions and static functions in C - language. I thought local and static functions are same? Is it right or wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Local and `static` in the case you described are synonyms, however, `static` is the keyword that you use to make a function local (i.e. private).  Global functions are not private to the source file they're defined in.  They can be `extern`ed to other source files, typically by including the header file for the function you want's source file.